# Jobs running on driver node databrick

Tags: python, databricks

I have notebook that runs a machine learning jobs in databrick, i'm using dbutils to accept variables and pass that to notebook.

I have created another notebook as parent and pass variables via this notebook and run multiple notebook with.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor, ProcessPoolExecutor
def processAnIntegerNumber(id):

dbutils.notebook.run(path = "/Users/child_notebook",
                                    timeout_seconds = 3600,
                                    arguments = {"id":id})
```

this will create multiple jobs, the problem that I have is all these 10-30 jobs that I pass as variable runs in Driver nodes and does not use worker nodes and as result it's extremely slow.

anyway to run python notebook in parallel, without using scala?

regards